# Paginar JSON con js

Tags: javascript, html, json, nodejs, paginación

Hola amigos estoy tratando de paginas este JSON

```
{
    "success": {
        "data": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "id_proyecto": 1,
                "id_usercreated": 2,
                "img1": "29f64cb637e74b83dfe9e0e233650293f967.jpg",
                "img2": "1322fa112dc68747273a6829cb24b7396392.jpg",
                "img3": "4b486476009f64182898f5832c6b6aeb9144.jpg",
                "imgh": "129ef14087792fc7ff7e2190f4776faa9a1c.39",
                "text1": "LoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLorem",
                "text2": "LoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLorem",
                "text3": "LoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLorem",
                "title": "Solares sustentables en la Huasteca Veracruzana",
                "created_at": "2019-03-25T12:14:33.000Z"
            },{otros objetos}] }}
```

y esta función para recibir  y paginar.

```
function pagintaionNews(){
    $.ajax({

        url: '/pag-news',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: "json",
        data:{
            page: 1,
            pagelimit: 10
        },
        success: (data) =>{

            console.log(data)

        },
        error: (jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown) =>{
            console.log(jqXHR);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });


}
```

Pero no consigo reducir el numero de objetos entrantes, alguien puede decirme como puedo construir correctamente una paginación con un json de este tipo? acaso me estoy olvidando de algo??

Comment: Hola, ¿tú API rest o servicio soporta la paginación?, podríamos empezar por ahí o recibes todos los datos y deseas paginar desde el lado del cliente(con js)?

Comment: estoy usando express y knex js , quiero paginar desde el lado del cliente